# My if function in pascal doesnt work as i want it to

Tags: pascal

i'm having some problems with `if,then,else` in pascal . I've just started making something like a quiz and i encountered some problems . Here is my code :

```
program question;

var a:char;

 begin
 writeln('Whats the capital of France?');
 readln(a);

 if a='Paris' then
    writeln('Correct answer!!')
 else
    writeln ('Wrong answer!!');

 readln
 end.
```

Second part works fine if answer isnt paris than says its wrong thats fine but the first part doesnt really work . When i answer paris it says its wrong answer . So if anyone could help me out i would be really thankful.

Comment: Make sure you type Paris and not paris

Comment: You declared "a" a "char", it cannot ever be "Paris" but "P". Make it a string.

Comment: Just to underline what @SertacAkyuz says, the reason your code wasn't doing what you expected is that a `Char` variable can only ever hold a single character at a time, like 'p' or 'P',so testing its value against a multi-character string like 'paris' will always fail. Depending on which Pascal compiler you are using, you may find that it emitted a warning about this during compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to lowercase or uppercase your answer in order to make a case insensitive question. Also the value that you compare in the if must be lowercase to it work. You must also use the type string for your `a` variable:

```
program question;

var a: string;

 begin
 writeln('Whats the capital of France?');
 readln(a);
 a := LowerCase(a);

 if a='paris' then
    writeln('Correct answer!!')
 else
    writeln ('Wrong answer!!');

 readln
 end.
```

This happens because "Paris" is not equal to "paris" or "PARIS".

You cam check this working here: https://onlinegdb.com/HJQiZwoiB